# Filtering on node whose user ID is equal to the current user

Tags: 7, views

In Drupal 6 you can have a filter `node.uid = current user`. How do you do this in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 27):

You need to add the filter as a "context" (Advanced) where you can supply a default argument. If you context is for a user, like the node author, then you can select stuff like id of logged in user.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: I've always used Relationships but will look at contexts too.  View's is awesome.

Comment: Going to modify about 100 views. :)  Thank you for the details @googletorp.

Comment: you notice the first line of text in the context filter?  "When the filter value is not in the URL"  so I tried this already and it works if the url does not have a users id in it but if user a is looking at some user b profile then this view is going to use users b id not users a

Answer (score 22):

You need to edit your view, go to the Advanced column (far right) and add a new relationship.

[image: Add Relationship]

You will specifically need to add the "Content: Author" relationship.

Next, under "Filters" you will need to add the "User: Current" filter.

[image: Add Filter]

Now you should be able to filter content owned by the currently logged in user.

Comment: While this work, this is slower than the using context filters, as you need to create a join. It's probably only a few ms slower, but no reason to waste resources.

Comment: This will save way more than a few ms on a bunch of my queries. :) Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score -2):

you can add simply

"User: Current" in "Filter" criteria.

Comment: Not enough explanation here for people to follow