# Is it possible to use a path like that : user/%user/word with MENU_NORMAL_ITEM instead of MENU_LOCAL_TASK

Tags: 7, uri, routes

i hope you understood the title of my topic because i have difficulties to express this problem in english.

I would like to change the menu item which is a tab (saved searches) and put it on my menu block.

[image]

So i went to the files of the module and found this:

`search_api_saved_searches.module`

```
$items['user/%user/saved-searches'] = array(
'title' => 'Saved searches',
'description' => 'View and edit your saved searches.',
'page callback' => 'search_api_saved_searches_user_listing',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' => 'search_api_saved_search_edit_access',
'access arguments' => array(1),
'weight' => 5,
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
'file' => 'search_api_saved_searches.pages.inc',
);
```

I know that `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` is a generally a tab, so i tried `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM` but it didn't work.

I tried some other thing and removed %user `$items['user/saved-searches']` but after that i had many error, i tried to debug them but after many hours i stopped, it was clearly not a good solution to change code directly on a module.

**So my question is**: Is there a easy way to move a menu item from a tab to a menu block when the path has a wildcard components ? If it's not possible, do you think there is, maybe, a workaround to accomplish what i want to do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used views to achieve what i wanted to do but it was not easy because :

- Fields was not the same and didn't have the good format
- There was no filter "current user"
  So i create a custom template using `views-view-table.tpl.php`.

I don't know if what i did is very good:

- I call `global $user` in my template, maybe it's a mistake, i don't know if we can do that
  **Thxs to criticguy, i improved the following code by removing current user test**

  ```
   <?php foreach ($rows as $row_count => $row): ?>
      <tr <?php if ($row_classes[$row_count]) { print 'class="' . implode(' ', $row_classes[$row_count]) .'"';  } ?>>
      <?php foreach ($row as $field => $content): ?>
       <td <?php if ($field_classes[$field][$row_count]) { print 'class="'. $field_classes[$field][$row_count] . '" '; } ?><?php print drupal_attributes($field_attributes[$field][$row_count]); ?>>
       <?php if($field == 'last_execute') : ?>
         <?php $last_execute = t('@time ago', array('@time' => format_interval(REQUEST_TIME - $content))); ?>
           <?php print $last_execute; ?>
         <?php elseif($field == 'created'): ?>    
           <?php $created = format_date($content, 'short'); ?>
           <?php print $created; ?>
         <?php elseif($field == 'notify_interval'): ?>    
           <?php $interval = format_interval($content, 1); ?>
            <?php print $interval; ?>
         <?php elseif($field == 'results'): ?>  
            <?php $tab = explode(',', $content); ?>
            <?php $x = 1 ?>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach($tab as $value): ?>
              <li>
              <?php print '<a href="'.url().'node/'.$value.'">Resultat '.$x.'</a>'; ?>
              </li>
              <?php $x++ ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul> 
         <?php else: ?>
          <?php print $content; ?>    
         <?php endif ?>
    </td>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  ```

Final result:
[image: saved search]
I'm always interested by my question about MENU_NORMAL_ITEM and MENU_LOCAL_TASK.

Comment: For "current user" in views, see @googletorp's answer here. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/22431/1747