# Create a view with user filter by default and all users after reset

Tags: views, users

I come here because i want to create a view who display all content of type "Document" of my website, but by default i want to show the content of type "Document" of the user connected. And after when i click on the button reset of the view, i want to see all content of type "Document" of all users.

For example the view when i come on the page :

Me | document 1
Me | document 3
Me | document 4
Me | document 6

When i reset the view :

Me | document 1
Jean | document 2
Me | document 3
Me | document 4
Jean | document 5
Me | document 6
Mickael | document 7

this is possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. What you want to look into here is the concept of Views Contextual Filters. So you'll set this up something like this:

[image: Contextual Filters]

This will allow you to have a default view that works on the currently logged in user. Then you can setup another Exposed Filter which shows all authors. Hope this helps.

*Thanks to [this somewhat related post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22427/drupal-7-view-filtering-on-node-uid-equal-to-current-user) for the image.*

Comment: thanks for that image it works ! by default i have my view filtered by user connected. but when i reset the view, the contextual filter stay and i see the nodes by author. How can i remove a contextual filter on reset ?

Comment: This is where things get a little more tricky because you're already using the default value. So you have 2 options:Have two displays of the same view. One that shows filtered by author and one that is *all* posts. Then simply add a link in the Header portion of the view to "Show All" which would bounce people to the other view. Similarly show a link on the author filtered view

Comment: oh ok. i tried to pass the id of user in the url like : mydocument/150, it works i got thedocument by user 150 and to display the document of all user i put a button in the header without id user in url like : mydocument  . i think it's the best solution... Because the reset button doesn't remove the id user in url...

Comment: Awesome! Sometimes Drupal is just thinking a little out of the box. :) If this helped you don't forget to mark the answer accepted and good luck with your site!